# How to write JUnit test case for following code using Grails?

Tags: grails, junit

How to write JUnit test case for following code using Grails?

Using Grails 2.4.4 and JDK 1.7.

`getLastUploadAlertDate` is one of the methods in a service class and I am trying to write JUnit for it.

```
public Map getLastUploadAlertDate(Long patientId) 
  {

    log.debug("Enter(Method) - RS- LUP{}")
    Map result = [:]

    try {
        Sql db = new Sql(dataSource)
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
        String q = "select max(reminder_date) from reminder_history where trigger_type = 2 and user_id = ${patientId}"
        def rawDate = db.firstRow(q)
        String strDate = (rawDate.getAt(0)).toString()
        if(!strDate.equals("null") || strDate != "null") {
            Date date = sdf.parse(strDate)
            result.status = true
            result.date = date
            return result
        }
        else {
            result.status = false
            return result
            }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception while getLastUploadAlertDate" + e)
        result.status = false
        return result
        }
}
```

As of my knowledge i wrote test case for it as follows:

```
  void test_getLastUploadAlertDate_UT_01(){
    ReminderService reminderService = new ReminderService()
    Long patientId 
    boolean status = false
    def dataSource=mockFor(DataSource)
    reminderService.dataSource=dataSource.createMock()
    def sql=mockFor(Sql)
    sql.demand.static.firstRow{String query, LinkedHashMap params->
        return
    }
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = null
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")
    sdf.setLenient(false)
    def rawDate=mockFor(Date)
    rawDate.demand.static.firstRow{String query, LinkedHashMap params->
        return
    }
    Map result = reminderService.getLastUploadAlertDate(patientId)
    assertEquals false, status
}
```

and I got Exception like this

> Error | 2017-10-19 11:48:16,161 [main] ERROR hcp.ReminderService  -
>   Exception while
>   getLastAdherenceAlertInDaysgroovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException:
>   Ambiguous method overloading for method groovy.sql.Sql#. Cannot
>   resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping
>   prototypes between:   [interface java.sql.Connection]     [interface
>   javax.sql.DataSource]
>
> Error | 2017-10-19 11:48:16,161 [main] ERROR
>   hcp.ReminderService  - Exception while
>   getLastUploadAlertInDaysgroovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous
>   method overloading for method groovy.sql.Sql#. Cannot resolve
>   which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes
>   between:  [interface java.sql.Connection]     [interface
>   javax.sql.DataSource]

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code? What is this method trying to achieve? Why don't you use classic Grails artifacts such as controller, service and domain class?

Comment: I have added some more Logic in it and it is one of the closure in a service class

Comment: do you have any examples of your unit test to share with us? Or can you describe what you are trying to test? And can you explain why you are working with `Sql` object instead of GORM?

Comment: It should be fairly straightforward to test this code.  In your JUnit Integration test, add a the statement `def dataSource`, which should be populated automatically and can be used to create a SQL connection for your tests.  You can then create whatever object contains your method getLastUploadAlertDate() and if necessary, populate that object's dataSource with the one created for you in your test object.  You should then have all the tools required to write your tests.  Unless your question is more complicated than that....

Comment: As you said I have done some junit for that closure but I got some errors as mentioned above. please help me to rectify the code